# iTextSharp CreateLink / JavaScript annotation not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm getting a memory stream in and then trying to append a link annotation with calls some JavaScript. Simply put my code looks like:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(streamFromSharePoint);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfMemoryStream);

iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100f,500f,200f,600f);
PdfName n = new PdfName("Name");
PdfAction a = PdfAction.JavaScript("alert('hi');", pdfStamper.Writer);
PdfAnnotation l = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(pdfStamper.Writer,r,n,a);

pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(l,1);

pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
pdfStamper.Close();
```

I can see a box on the screen for the border, but clicking on it does nothing. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ECMAScript / JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) is not the same as [Acrobat's JavaScript](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf). try replacing:

```
"alert('hi');"
```

with:

```
"app.alert('hi');"
```

Comment: Bingo.  There's probably an error message in the JS log.  To see that log in Reader, you need to enable it via the JS preferences.  Kind of a pain.